# Ruby week number results

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, datetime

Why when I use

```
Time.now.strftime('%Y%W')
```

or

```
Date.today.strftime('%Y%W')
```

they return 201912 while it should be 201913 as we are in week 13, not 12.

How to get the current week number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Time.now.strftime('%Y%V')
```

Would give you the output your looking for.

> %V - Week number of the week-based year (01..53)

You have to look for the week-based year.

Answer (score 5):

If you look in the documentation, it says this:

```
Week number: The first week of YYYY that starts with a Sunday or
Monday (according to %U or %W). The days in the year before the first
week are in week 0.

  %U - Week number of the year. The week starts with Sunday. (00..53)
  %W - Week number of the year. The week starts with Monday. (00..53)
```

January 1st, 2019 was on a Tuesday, so that would have been week 0 - making today week 12.